# Model evaluation throwing "required broadcastable shapes" error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to evaluate a model using `model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)` where, `X_test` and `Y_test` are the test sets obtained from `cifar10` datasets. While evaluating the model, I get this error. Not sure, why I'm getting this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Node: 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]] [Op:__inference_test_function_1521711]
```

The way that I'm obtaining `X_test` and `Y_test` is given below:

```
#import all required libaries
from keras.datasets import cifar10 
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model, Sequential 
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.models import load_model 
from keras.losses import msle
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #visualization library

#load training and test dataset  from cifar10 dataset
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

# Unit normalizing 
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')/255 
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')/255 


# Reshaping training and test datasets
X_train = X_train.reshape(len(X_train),X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],3) 
print(X_train.shape) #(50000, 32, 32, 3)
print(X_test.shape) #(10000, 32, 32, 3)
print(Y_test.shape) #(10000, 1)

def build_autoencoder(img_shape):
    # The encoder network
    encoder = Sequential()
    encoder.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=img_shape)) # 32x32x32
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization()) # 32x32x32
    encoder.add(MaxPooling2D(2, padding='same')) # 16x16x32
    encoder.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))  # 16x16x16
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())  # 16x16x16
    encoder.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')) # 16x16x8
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization()) # 16x16x8
    encoder.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')) # 16x16x8
    
    # The decoder network
    decoder = Sequential()
    decoder.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')) # 16x16x32
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization()) # 16x16x32
    decoder.add(UpSampling2D()) # 32x32x32
    decoder.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')) # 16x16x16
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization()) # 16x16x16
    decoder.add(UpSampling2D()) # 32x32x16
    decoder.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')) # 32x32x16
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization()) # 32x32x16
    decoder.add(Conv2D(3,  kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')) # 32x32x3
    
    return encoder, decoder

IMG_SHAPE = X_train.shape[1:] #(32, 32, 3)
input_img = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE) #create image input
encoder, decoder = build_autoencoder(IMG_SHAPE)
code = encoder(input_img) #encode image
reconstruction = decoder(code) #decoder image
autoencoder = Model(input_img,reconstruction) #create autoencoder model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], loss='mean_squared_error') # compile model using adam optimizer and measure loss using mean_squared_error
print(autoencoder.summary())
```

Here's the summary of the modal.

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
                                                                 
 sequential (Sequential)     (None, 16, 16, 8)         7488      
                                                                 
 sequential_1 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 32, 3)         9587      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 17,075
Trainable params: 16,835
Non-trainable params: 240
_________________________________________________________________

autoencoder.fit(x=X_train, y=X_train,
                validation_data=[X_test, X_test],  batch_size=32, epochs=200)
 
#evaluate the model
autoencoder.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)



The error that it throws.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-976ff2f8b7a2> in <module>()
----> 1 autoencoder.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-29-976ff2f8b7a2>", line 1, in <module>
      autoencoder.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1716, in evaluate
      tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1525, in test_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1514, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1507, in run_step
      outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1473, in test_step
      self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1329, in mean_squared_error
      return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
Node: 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]] [Op:__inference_test_function_1521711]
```

Comment: Where are you exactly reshaping X_test?

Comment: You need to include a reproducible example, at least something complete, it is very unclear why you are using mean squared error, and what your model predicts exactly.

Comment: @MojtabaAbdiKh. I'm not reshaping the `X_test` anywhere. Do I have to reshape it?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I've updated my question and also provided the source code.

Comment: You need to reshape X_test to similar shape as of the training set.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Any idea on how to reshape it?